# JavaFx, outlining the text of a label

Tags: css, javafx

I have some text which uses a dark gray fill color. I'm however using a pretty dark background as well and I'd like it to stand out a little more. I can't change the fill color but adding an "outline color" would help me out. So, I checked for other similar questions and only found one, which was answered 5 years ago and doesn't seem to work anymore. I tried, using css, to use the following options:

-fx-border = It outlines the entire node (Rectangle) instead of the text

-fx-stroke = No apparent results, even with width/color

So the question is, can I outline the text of a certain label and color it, and if so, how ?

Comment: I checked that and tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried it again on OS X 10.12.6 with Java 9.0.4, by copy and pasting the code from the answer to that question.  It worked just fine for me, providing the output image displayed in the answer.

Comment: I tried it a few minutes ago on 1.8.0 (update 141 or so - not at the computer right now) and it worked just fine for me too.

Comment: @jewelsea What do you apply the stroke parameters to ? I tried applying it to .label and it doesn't work. In the other question, it's applied to ".outline.label.text". What's that for ? As far as I know, there's no such thing as a .text ? And what's that .outline for ?

Comment: @AdamDube The answer to the linked question contains a complete example that you can copy, paste, and run. Did you try it exactly as it is? The screenshot in that code was created by running the code posted there.

Comment: @James_D I got it, sorry about that... I wasn't using the code version and tried to only use fxml, but I had to use some of the code too...

Comment: @AdamDube You should be able to do it in FXML, just add `styleClass="outline"` to the `<Label>` and specify the style sheet on the root element.

Comment: In the linked code there a line `label.getStyleClass().add("outline");`, that sets a custom style class for a label where you want the text outlined.  It could have been the word "foo" instead of "outline", I just used "outline" because it made sense in this context.  The ".text" in the selector is to specify the text in the label.  Note that the selector used in the sample has a space: ".outline.label .text", which is different from what you noted in your comment Adam.   And yeah, the definition of ".text" is not documented anywhere that I know of ;-)

Comment: @jewelsea That helped a lot, thanks :)